# Overriding a js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm working on a spree project and trying to override the admin.js.erb file in the spree_core external library. This works fine when simply overriding a js file, but when the js file has an extension, it will ignore it / just compile them both. Is this a bug with rails not knowing how to overide an extended js file or simply I need to set a configuration somewhere to allow this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a Sprokets bug, but I wasn't able to nail it down.  As a workaround, you can create a new file name, like overrides.js and require it in all.js:

```
//= require admin/overrides
```

Most of the the things in admin/admin.js.erb can be overridden by just redefining the variable.  For the jQuery bindings, you can unbind the old one and bind your new one on.